# #DEFINE в C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, препроцессор

Прогаю на *С#* в *Unity*, нередко используя команды препроцессора `#if/#endif`, `#region/#endregion` и прочие.

Однако я помню такую команду как `#define` (когда-то давно приходилось пользоваться), но нигде не могу найти её. Может, нужна доп. библиотека, или `#define` реально нет? Просто это удобней, чем создавать константную переменную.

Comment: Ее define просто нет, используются при описании константы только

Comment: Мдэ. Ну ладно. Edit: хм, ты комментируешь, хотя это ответ на мой вопрос. Ну лан.

Comment: Вы просто перепутали языки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#define` в c# используется только для определения символов условной компиляции, которые потом можно проверять в `#if` или `ConditionalAttribute`. Использовать его для создания макроопределений, как в с/с++, нельзя. Для этих целей используются константы времени компиляции, объявляемые с помощью ключевого слова `const`.